# Trouble extracting key from JSON data

Tags: python, json, dictionary, for-loop

I have a JSON data, below are images of part of the data

[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9Txw.png)
[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4oco.png)

Through this data, i would like to extract the "text" and "indices" values, which are sub-keys that can be found in the key "entities". I tried doing this using the method below

```
with open('tweets.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for item in data:
    for key, value in item['entities'].items():
        for v in value:
            if value:
                s_index = (v['indices'][0])
                e_index = (v['indices'][1])
                all_texts = (v['text'])
```

i managed to retrieve the "indices" value to store them into their respective attributes. However i am having trouble receiving the "text" value, as they said that there is a key error, as shown below

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5729d0d2fa15> in <module>
     12                 s_index = (v['indices'][0])
     13                 e_index = (v['indices'][1])
---> 14                 all_texts = (v['text'])
     15 
     16 #cur.execute('INSERT INTO entities (tweet_id, type, value, start_index, end_index) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',

KeyError: 'text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because some "entities" do not have the attribute "key" in them.

Instead of selecting the "text" like this `v['text']`, you could use `v.get('text')` which returns `None` if the key does not exist, and then treat the `None` value. And actually, you should do that for "indices" too.

You can also check that your variable `key` corresponds to the entity type you want (for instance "hashtags"), since each entity has different attributes.

See the [Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/entities).

Comment: Thank you so much! I am a beginner to this and i understand better now, appreciate it

Comment: I am sorry i tried but i can't upvote it as i do not have enough reputation!